# js-tree multiple instances issue

Tags: jstree

I have multiple instances of jstree. I am using js-tree.directive.

```
var selectedNode = $('js-tree').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0];
var parentNodeId = $('js-tree').jstree("get_parent",selectedNode);`
```

but `parentNodeId` is returning `false`. It does not understand which tree it is on.
I want `ParentNodeId`.

Regards
Sonal

Comment: What selector are you using? It can't be just `js-tree`. Did you mean id `$('#js-tree')` or class `$('.js-tree')` ?

Comment: `<div id="js-tree" class="js-tree-view">
    <js-tree tree-plugins="contextmenu,types,search"
     tree-types="typesConfig" tree-contextmenu="contextMenu"
     tree-ajax="{{treeData[1]}}"
     tree-events="ready:readyCB;changed:changedCB;open_node:openNodeCB;dblclick:DoubleClickOnNode"></js-tree>    
   </div>`

I am using js-tree directive and angular to bind the tree events and data